# Using a sum in place of 1/s in a laplace transform transfer function - is this allowed?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I found this transfer function online and for the most part I understand it. But what is tripping me up, is that they are replacing the traditional $\frac{1}{s}$ form of the integral with a sum. I understand the reasoning -- an integral is just an infinite sum, so a discrete version is a finite sum -- but I didn't realize that was allowed. Is this acceptable, and if so, are there any rules or concerns to consider?

**Aside:**

I should also note that the document doesn't say which method they used to convert to the discrete domain, I'm just assuming it's a laplace transform because the derivative term comes out as a multiplicand, and I don't think that happens in a fourier transform. These are the only 2 discrete transforms I'm aware of, so maybe that's my confusion.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to have much at all to do with laplace or fourier transforms. Instead, you have a continuous-time PID equation (eq. (1)) that is good and well-behaved for laplace analysis, and a discrete-time approximation (eq. (2)) which is how a PID might be implemented in a computer with finite sampling speed. If you have a high enough sampling speed, then analysis on (1) should apply to an implementation on (2).

Comment: @Angelica Thank you for your explanation. If you don't mind my asking, what would I look for for more information on discrete time transformations in general? As I mentioned, the only discrete time transformation I am familiar with is the DTFT.